# Android getting phone book update details

Tags: android, contacts

I have a requirement like when new contact is added in phone book my app has to get that new contact details added like name and phone number and has to print as a toast message.

Similarly when I delete contact I need to get toast message deleted contact details.

Please give me an idea of how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Use Broadcast Receiver

create service for that

When Contact has been added then your Service will be Executed and Toast eill be Displayed

and at detele time also you need to check

Comment: Just for your information, A Broadcast without an activity will not work on Android 3.0 or later versions.

Comment: Thank Brother I don't Know that. appreciate

Comment: You welcome, For more information Please read [Commonware's blog](http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/07/13/boot-completed-regression-confirmed.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use ContentObserver Class, if you change anything in contacts onChange method calls. Based on your requirements you can use it.

It definitely solve your problem.

```
public class test extends ContentObserver {

    public test(Handler handler) {
        super(handler);

    }

    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {

        Log.i("Contacts", "Contacs change");

        // It calls when new contact changes -add/edit/delete

    }

}
```